# Trazer um Objeto por um ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Estou com dificuldades em trazer os dados de uma pesquisa em Java, estou utilizando banco PostgreSQL e JDBC para persistência,

```
public List<Tapete> listarTapetes() {
    PreparedStatement state = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        String sql = "select * from Tapete order by preco";

        state = ConexaoPostgres.getConPostGres().prepareStatement(sql);

        rs = state.executeQuery();
        List<Tapete> listaTapetes = new ArrayList<Tapete>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Tapete tapete = new Tapete(//DUVIDA);
            listaTapetes.add(tapete);
        }

        return listaTapetes;
    }
```

o meu problema é o seguinte ali aonde tem o comentário (//DUVIDA). No meu objeto `Tapete`,  tenho uma variável do tipo `Forma` e outra do tipo `Material`:

```
private Material material;
private Forma forma;
```

Porém, não consigo fazer com o que o meu `ResultSet` me traga esses objetos, no meu banco eu defini material e forma como inteiros.

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Poderia mostrar uma representação de como está criado a sua tabela no BD? Não consegui entender muito bem sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

A cada execução de `rs.next()` o cursor que "aponta" para o resultado trazido pelo seu `SELECT` desce uma linha (ao contrário do que você possa pensar ele começa acima da primeira linha e não diretamente sobre a primeira linha). De forma que após o primeiro `rs.next()` ele está na linha 1, depois na linha 2, e assim por diante até ele retornar `false` e portanto sair do `while`, indicando que as linhas acabaram.

Seu objeto `rs` possui métodos que retornam o valor de cada coluna da linha em que o cursor está atualmente posicionado. Veja a documentação de [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) e procure conhecer seus métodos principais, como `getInt()` para trazer um campo INTEGER, `getString()` para trazer um campo CHAR ou VARCHAR, etc.

Observe que esses métodos podem ser chamados passando-se como parâmetro o nome de uma coluna da tabela ou então a numeração da mesma dependendo da ordem que as colunas estão no banco, por exemplo `getInt("material")` ou `getInt(1)`. Escolha a forma que achar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Eu já fiz algo parecido com o que você precisa fazer, você vai ter as seguintes classes:

- Tapete.java
- TapeteBD.java

Meu exemplo está supondo que Material e Forma também são tabelas do seu banco, no caso, são chaves estrangeiras. No meu exemplo colocarei um atributo NOME só para ilustração.

A classe Tapete.java será o nosso bean, nela você terá apenas os atributos e seus respectivos getters and setters, as classes Forma e Material também precisarão ter esse mesmo bean, e a mesma classe de banco de dados (supondo que material e forma estejam no banco de dados).

```
class Tapete {
     private String nome;
     private Material material;
     private Forma forma;

     //getters and setters
}
```

Na classe TapeteBD teremos um método parecido com o seu listarTapetes(), vamos chamar de getTapetes() que será reponsável pela consulta e retornará a lista.

```
class TapeteBD {
    //Métodos de conexão etc.

    private ResultSet rs = null; 
    private MaterialBD mbd = new MaterialBD(); //Criamos a classe que irá retornar o objeto Material.
    private FormaBD fbd = new FormaBD(); //Criamos a classe que irá retornar o objeto Forma.

   /* Essaes dois objetos, formaBD e MaterialBD serão responsáveis por chamar um método getMaterial() e getForma() respectivamente, já que o tapete recebe também dois objetos. */

public List<Tapete> getTapetes() throws SQLException {

    String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Tapete ORDER BY preco";
    Tapete tapete = null; //Definimos o objeto tapete que terá seus atributos recuperados do banco de dados posteriormente.
    Material material = null; //Definimos o objeto material que será recuperado do banco de dados posteriormente.
    Forma forma = null; //Definimos o objeto forma que será recuperado do banco de dados posteriormente.
    List<Tapete> tapetes = new ArrayList<Tapete>;

    state = ConexaoPostgres.getConPostGres().prepareStatement(sql); //Essa parte da conexão eu não sei se está correta, pois não to com os arquivos aqui, só copiei o que você já tinha feito.
    rs = state.executeQuery();

    if(rs!=null) {
         rs.beforeFirst(); //Posiciona o cursos antes do primeiro elemento.
         while(rs.next()) {
             tapete = new Tapete(); //Criamos o tapete para setarmos os atributos de acordo com os dados recuperados do banco.
             tapete.setNome(rs.getString("nome"); //Setamos o nome de acordo com o recuperado do campo nome da tabela tapete no banco de dados.
             material = mbd.getMaterial(rs.getInt("codigo_material"); //Temos que ter uma classe de banco de dados para material para poder recuperar o objeto Material de acordo com sua chave estrangeira.
             forma = fbd.getForma(rs.getInt("codigo_forma");

             if(material != null) {
                  tapete.setMaterial(material); 
             }

             if(forma != null) {
                  tapete.setForma(forma);
             }

             tapetes.add(tapete); //Adicionamos o tapete com os atributos na lista.
         }
    }
return tapetes; //Retornamos a lista para o método que o chamou.
}
```

Faz tempo que fiz esse código, e não o tenho mais comigo e nem tenho IDE para testa-lo aqui, deve haver alguns erros, mas no mais acho que dá pra entender. Qualquer coisa só perguntar. Um abraço.

**EDITADO**

Não tinha lido que você tinha definido Material e Forma como inteiros, esses inteiros são chaves estrangeiras para outra tabela? Se forem o exemplo serve perfeitamente. Só terá que criar as classes:

- Forma.java
- FormaBD.java
- Material.java
- MaterialBD.java

Com a estrutura um pouco parecida, acho que com isso você já deve saber mais ou menos como prosseguir.